# Any tutorials available for using X Dev Api in MySql Document db in Java application

Tags: mysql-x-devapi

the official XDevApi user guide for using MySql document store for java applications is not very descriptive when it comes to doing CRUD operation.
Are there any tutorials available for easy of learning and using this in my spring boot java application
official guide:https://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/working-with-collections-basic-crud.html